# How to Show video list on homepage from the database?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net

I uploaded videos to the server and saved the videopath and imagepath into the database. Now I want to show the video lists on my homepage. I wrote the code, the player for streaming the video is appeared but not the list of the videos.
the codes are - 
C# Code Behind -

```
        [WebMethod]
    public static List<Video> loadVideo(string value)
    {
        IList<Video> video = VideoManager.GetHomePageVideo();
        if (video == null)
        {
            video = new List<Video>();
        }
        return video.ToList();
    }
```

And the HTML and JavaScript Code for -

```
    PageMethods.loadVideo('', loadVideoSuccess);
function loadVideoSuccess(result) {
            $("#dvVideo").html('');
            var html = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                html += "<div style=\" border: solid 1px gray;\">";
                html += "<a style=\"cursor: pointer;\" onclick=\"LoadVideo('" + result[i].VideoPath.split('/')[1] + "');\"><img src=\"" + result[i].ImagePath + "\" width=\"70\" style=\"background-color:black;\" />" + resul[i].Title + "</a>";
                //html += " :: <a href=\"Pages/Gallery/Videos.aspx?videoId=" + result[i].ID + " " + result[i].Title + </a>;
                html += "</div>";
            }
            $("#dvVideo").append(html);
        }
<div class="widget-main">
                 <div class="widget-main-title">
                     <h4 class="widget-title">Latest Videos</h4>


                 </div>
                  <div class="widget-inner" id="dvVideo">
                     <div style="">
                            <div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <script type="text/javascript">
                      jwplayer("myElement").setup({
                          file: "Uploads/Ar_Rahman_Edited.mp3",
                          image: "video/RoboCop.jpg",
                          height: 320,
                          width: 332,
                          skin: "jwplayer-skins/six.xml"
                      });
                      function loadVideo(file) {
                          var filename = 'Uploads/' + file;
                          jwplayer("myElement").setup({
                              file: filename,
                              image: "video/RoboCop.jpg",
                              height: 320,
                              width: 332,
                              autostart: true,
                              skin: "jwplayer-skins/six.xml"
                          });
                      }
                   </script> 
                 </div>
```

Now please help me why it is not showing the video list on my homepage ? What should I do for it?

Comment: are you getting the result in your javascript function "loadvideosuccess" ?? You have to make an ajax call to your aspnet page to get the result.

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors? Have to tried to log and see which javascript functions are executing?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the link below and try that way and please don't try mix and mess up html and javascript together. Keep both separate.

```js
//http://jsfiddle.net/ramp/nF7Mw/
```